# Managing various printing conditions cleanly?

Tags: python

I have the following code which prints the data I have available but currently  looks bad and cluttered:

```
has_printed = 0
output = ''

is_banner_printed = 0
if time.time() > next_print_time:
    output = output + (' ' + datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S %p") + ' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------c')
    is_banner_printed = 1

if is_banner_printed or not(len(self.post_list)):
    print(output)

output = ''
for i, post in enumerate(self.post_list):

    post.update()

    output = output + ('   Age: ' + datetime.fromtimestamp(self.utils.get_submission_age(post.created_utc)).strftime("%M:%S") +
                       ' | URL: http://url.com/' + post.id +
                       ' | Score: ' + str(post.score).ljust(6, ' ') + ... )
    if i == 0:
        output = '\n' + output
    output = output + '\n'

if output is not '' and time.time() > next_print_time and is_banner_printed:
    print(output)
    has_printed = 1
    next_print_time = time.time() + self.PRINT_RATE

if has_printed:
    print(' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------c\n\n\n')
elif is_banner_printed and output is '':
    print('')
    next_print_time = time.time() + self.PRINT_RATE
```

I wonder if it's possible to clean this mess to make the actual code readable?

Comment: in `has_printed` you can use `False/True` instead of `0/1`.

Comment: first you could create list with all `post.string` and later use `"\n".join(output)` to convert list wiht strings into one string.

Comment: instead of `output = output + something` you can write `output += something`

Comment: instead of `+` to concatenate strings you can use string formating `"Age: {} | URL: {} | Score: {}".format(time, post.id, post.score)`

Comment: you can generate string with datetime before you concatenate it with other strings - this way you will have two shorter lines instead of one very long line of code.

Comment: probably portal [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) can be better place for your question.